# Listview Checkbox for Selecting Rows is Raised 2 Times

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, listview

```
$('#NewClientsTable').on('click', 'tr', function (e) { 
    var $r= $(this).closest('tr');

    if ($r.find('input[type=checkbox]').eq(0).is(':checked'){
         // Do Stuff
    } else { // Do Stuff }
});
```

In this function I'm catching any click on TR inside ListView to :

1. Highlight the row.
2. Make the Checkbox ... checked

in Console I tried to trace the events by Console.log().. But I find out that:

- IF I CLICK on THE (checkbox), **THIS EVENT WILL BE FIRED 2 TIMES, ONE FOR THE (TR) AND THE OTHER ONE FOR (CHECKBOX)**
- IF I CLICK ON THE (ROW) IT SELF, **THIS EVENT WILL BE FIRED 1 TIME ONLY FOR (TR) ONLY**

('#NewClientsTable') => Table inside ItemTemplate

How can we fire the event one time only if we click the Checkbox??

Comment: Use `event.stopPropagation()` in the `checkbox` event handler

Comment: copy and paste rendered markup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To stop event from firing on `TR` tag children, do something like this:

```
$("#NewClientsTable tr input[type='checkbox']").click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

**Here is a demo:**

```js
$("tr").click(function(event){
  alert("works");
  $(this).toggleClass("mycolor");
});
$("tr input[type='checkbox']").click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(this).closest('tr').toggleClass("mycolor");
});
```

```css
.mycolor{ background-color:green;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="check" ></td><td>test2</td></tr>
  <tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="check2" ></td><td>test2</td></tr>
<table>
```

> In this demo you will notice that, if you click on the check box, nothing happens, but if you click on the row, the event fires

Comment: ... I've 2 functions like your Example. but I want those to functions to do same thing. 1- Check the checkbox. 2. Highlight the Row.

Comment: But the Event is raised 2 times if I click the Checkbox

Comment: @Developer please check my updated demo, if you click the row it changes color, but if you click the checkbox, it only checks it....if you click again on the highlighted row, it removes the highlight, vise versa

Comment: ... You're right. what about if I WANT TO Change the color also when I check the checkbox?? The event will be fired 2 times.?

Comment: ...    Got My Point ??

Comment: @Developer okay i updated my demo to satify your requirement, check it again, the event fires once

Comment: Luthando Loot You're right but I've something wrong in my rendered HTML, I'll share the code today.

Comment: Thanks Man, Solved. My problem was - wrapped the checkbox inside <label> for styling purposes.

Comment: @Developer i am glad my answer helped you

Answer (score 1):

You need to attach `event.stopPropagation()` inside checkbox event handler to stop from bubbling up. Suppose you have this below event for checkbox click event :

```
// selector and context depend on your original code
$('#NewClientsTable').on('click', 'input[type="checkbox"]', (function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  // another rest of the code
});
```